# Gitlab 500 error on viewing file sources on Mountain Lion Server

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion, gitlab

And another Problem.

If I try to view the content of an File in the Files Tab, nothing is shown.

After a quick look at the production.log I found the following:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 149ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Failed to get header.):
    9:   .file_content.code
    10:     - unless blob.empty?
    11:       %div{class: user_color_scheme_class}
    12:         = raw blob.colorize(formatter: :gitlab)
    13:     - else
    14:       %p.nothing_here_message Empty file
  app/models/tree.rb:6:in `colorize'
  app/views/tree/blob/_text.html.haml:12:in `_app_views_tree_blob__text_html_haml__2117416289591340656_70112288282740'
  app/views/tree/_blob.html.haml:9:in `_app_views_tree__blob_html_haml__810415587318185235_70112333949220'
  app/views/tree/_tree.html.haml:19:in `_app_views_tree__tree_html_haml___380187574798250597_70112300103920'
  app/views/tree/show.js.haml:3:in `_app_views_tree_show_js_haml__4018035125126620215_70112300060420'
```

After some googling I found some Github issues which described it as an python version error.

I installed python via `brew install python`, it should be the right python installed. At least I get the right version from the console.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 11 2013, 16:34:20) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.24)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I just double checked the `bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production`

I think everything is fine, expect some things which are related to OS X, like the init script stuff.

```
Checking Environment ...

gitlab user is in gitg group? ... yes
Has no "-e" in ~gitolite/.profile ... yes
Git configured for gitlab user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking Gitolite ...

Using recommended version ... no
  Try fixing it:
  We strongly recommend using the version pointed out in the installation guide.
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "Gitolite"
Repo umask is 0007 in .gitolite.rc? ... yes
Allow all Git config keys in .gitolite.rc ... yes
Config directory exists? ... yes
Config directory owned by gitolite:gitg ... yes
Config directory access is drwxr-x---? ... yes
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by gitolite:gitg? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
Can clone gitolite-admin? ... yes
Can commit to gitolite-admin? ... yes
post-receive hook exists? ... yes
post-receive hook up-to-date? ... yes
post-receive hooks in repos are links: ... 
Some-Customer / Some Repo ... ok
Some-Customer / Some Repo ... ok
Some-Customer / Some Repo ... ok
Git config in repos: ... 
Some-Customer / Some Repo ... ok
Some-Customer / Some Repo ... ok
Some-Customer / Some Repo ... ok

Checking Gitolite ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  Install the init script
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
Init script up-to-date? ... can't check because of previous errors
Projects have satellites? ... 
Some-Customer / Some Repo ... yes
Some-Customer / Some Repo ... yes
Some-Customer / Some Repo ... yes

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be more than just a python version, as in "[Issue 2214](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2214)" or "[Issue 2272](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2272)".

Recent bugs like [Issue 2817](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2817) are still not addressed.

As mentioned in "[Issue 2410](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2410)", double-check the checks:

```
sudo -u gitlab -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```